# 'function' object has no attribute 'train_test_split'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am new to implementing Machine Learning in Python and am currently trying out KNN classification following YouTube tutorials. Here is the code.

```
import numpy as np
#from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt')
df.replace('?', -99999, inplace=True)
df.drop(['id'],1,inplace=True)

X=np.array(df.drop(['class'],1))
y=np.array(df['class'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=cross_validate.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
```

I get the following error: -

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=cross_validate.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'train_test_split'
```

I tried importing train_test_split as

```
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

but then I get the same error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`train_test_split` is a separate module ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)), and it is not to be used in combination with `cross_validate`; the correct usage here is (assuming scikit-learn v0.20):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# [...]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

sklearn.cross_validation **deprecated** in version 0.20.

Use sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split